# Issues with tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'd like to draw arrows on a table, to obtain the following picture

[image]

So I wrote down this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}|}
   \hline
   \tikzmark{A}{A} & \tikzmark{B}{B} & \tikzmark{C}{C} & \tikzmark{D}{D} & \tikzmark{E}{E} & 
   \tikzmark{F}{F}\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw [->] (pic cs:A) -- (pic cs:F);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it gives me this

[image]

instead of something like this (like I expect)

[image]

It's like the tikzpicture can't overlay the table, even if I have declared

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you compile the document twice?

Comment: I did it more than twice lol

Comment: Are you using the tikzmark library or did you include a definition in your preamble? Tikzmark went through a few variations on this site before it stabilised.

Comment: I included the tikz package in the preamble, and then I imported the library \usetikzlibrary(tikzmark) (still in the preamble)

Comment: @frad I've tried your code with a minimal preamble: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` and it has produced what I expected to see - an arrow across the cells of the table.  I tried with each of pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex. If you want to send me your full example, my email is on the tikzmark documentation. If you do send it, please also send the logfile and auxfile from your compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\tikzmarknode`. Or a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}|}
   \hline
   \tikzmarknode{A}{A} & \tikzmarknode{B}{B} & \tikzmarknode{C}{C} & \tikzmarknode{D}{D} & \tikzmarknode{E}{E} & 
   \tikzmarknode{F}{F}\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw [-stealth] (A.west) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,cells={nodes={draw}},column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
  (m){A & B & C & D & E & F\\};
  \draw[->] (m-1-2.north) -- ++ (0,2ex) -| (m-1-4);
  \draw[->] (m-1-2.south) -- ++ (0,-2ex) -| (m-1-1);
  \draw[->] (m-1-2.south) -- ++ (0,-1ex) -| (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just tried: if I write the code on a new empty document it works. If I do that in my original doc, it still gives me the original error. Is it because of some kind of conflict between packages?

Comment: @frad Hard to tell without knowing your document. Please try to produce a minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: @frad BTW, for your target picture it might be easier to use a `matrix` from `tikz`. Generally `tikzmark` won't know where the borders of the table are.

Comment: I'd like to use the tabular tbh, because I'll need to highlight a couple of rows of a table (like a red rectangle which includes some of the table rows). Is it still possible doing it using the tikz matrix instead of classical tabular?

Comment: @frad For that one I recommend the `nicematrix` package, which supports such features for tabulars.